# Contact form using HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, contact-form

I've made a contact form for a website (using HTML and JavaScript), my problem is: how can I actually send the message (email) to the recipient?

I found a way to do this in PHP, but I need a non-PHP solution. I've also heard I can so this using Outlook, but I'm not sure how I would do that.

Answer (score 0):

No, using JavaScript and HTML, you cannot and can never send an email, sending an Email requires SMTP server settings which would enable you to communicate with an Email Sending Server (Outlook in your case). Then you can provide the parameters such as: To, From, Subject, Body, Attachment etc and the Email Service provider would take care of the rest and the email will be sent!

Otherwise using Simple JavaScript you cannot send an Email to anyone and also you cannot get the email from anyone using just HTML and JavaScript. Its not what HTML and JavaScript are for. You're needing PHP or any other Server Side coding language for this thing!

Comment: Yes once you have code written in PHP, you can use your own Account details of Outlook of Gmail or anyother Email Service provider and you can send the Email! To anyone ... :)

Comment: What with VB? Can I do that with Visual Basic?

Comment: Yes, you can do that using VB.NET!

Answer (score 0):

If you want user to compose an email, you can simply use
`<a href="mailto:address@example.com">` on the webpage, clicking on this link would invoke Outlook on user's machine. See more on this [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_mailto)

If you want to use PHP, you can create a simple form in HTML with fields like from, to, subject, body etc. and on the server side, use PHP's mail() function to send the mail.

Comment: Nope, for me that opens mail.google.com because I have set Gmail as my Default email provider! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the operation of sending an email on the server side.
One simple and easy non PHP solution would be for example [nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/). You can create a simple express app then make it send email once it gets hit on a route for instance. There is a [short blog](https://codeburst.io/implementing-nodemailer-5-min-de2d2c781d6b) about it and many examples [here](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/264/how-to-send-an-email-gmail-outlook-and-zoho-using-nodemailer-in-node-js) that handle gmail, outlook etc

Answer (score -3):

PHP is the simplest option. I'm not too sure whether you can do it with Javascript and certainly not HTML. Check out http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/custom-php-contact-forms/ Its very simple